# continuity of product path--pasting lemma

Tags: general-topology

A path in a topological space $X$ is a continuous function $f:[0,1]\longrightarrow X$.

For two paths $f,g$ in $X$ such that $f(1)=g(0)$, the product path $f*g:[0,1]\longrightarrow X$, is defined by $f*g(t)= f(2t)$ when $t$ is within $[0, 1/2]$ and $f*g(t)=g(2t-1)$ when $t$ is within $[1/2, 1]$.

Prove that $f*g$ is continuous.

Okay I know the pasting lemma is needed to prove this but I'm really struggling on how to go about it.

Answer (score 1):

$[0,1/2]$ and $[1/2,1]$ are closed in $[0,1]$ and $f*g$ agrees on their intersection ,i.e., $\{1/2\}$...hence by pasting lemma $f*g$ is continuos as both $f$ and $g$ are continuous.